# Notify condition variable from boost::timed_wait only works once

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, asynchronous

I want to use `boost::timed_wait` to wait for an event or to timeout after 5 seconds. My problem is that my `timed_wait` only accepts the notification for the first time.

***To be more precise:***

I have some kind of little state machine. It does nothing more than just dispatch some Command asynchronously and then check if it was successfully. This means after dispatching the command my state machine calls `m_Condition.timed_wait(lock,timeout)`. (`m_Condition` is a member variable with the type `boost::condition_variable` ).

Now if this asynchronous call was successfull it shall call a callback function which notifies `m_Condition` so I know everything went OK. When the command failed it doesn't call the callback function and so my `timed_wait` should time out. So the callback function does nothing more and nothing less than calling `m_Condition.notify_all()`.

The problem is that this only works the first time. This means, after the first time `notify_all()` has been called it doesn't work with that condition variable again. I checked at my callback and it always calls `notify_all()` again but the `timed_wait` just times out.

Maybe some example code to make it a bit clearer:

myClass_A.hpp

```
class myClass_A
{
public:
    void runStateMachine();                 // Starts the state machine
    void callbackEvent();                   // Gets called when Async Command was successful
private:
    void stateMachine();                    // Contains the state machine
    void dispatchAsyncCommand();            // Dispatches an Asynchronous command
    boost::thread m_Thread;                 // Thread for the state machine
    boost::condition_variable m_Condition;  // Condition variable for timed_wait
    boost::mutex m_Mutex;                   // Mutex
};
```

myClass_A.cpp

```
void myClass_A::runStateMachine()
{
     m_Thread = boost::thread(boost::bind(&myClass_A,this));
}
void myClass_A::dispatchAsyncCommand()
{
     /* Dispatch some command Async and then return */
     /* The dispatched Command will call callbackEvent() when done */
}
void myClass_A::stateMachine()
{
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m_Mutex);
    while(true)
    {
        dispatchAsynCommand();
        if(!m_Condition.timed_wait(lock, boost::posix_time::milliseconds(5000)))
        {
            // Timeout
        }
        else
        {
            // Event
        }
    }
}
void myClass_A::callbackEvent()
{
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m_Mutex);
    m_Condition.notify_all();
}
```

So what can I do now? Is it not possible to use the condition_variable multiple times? Or do I need to reset it somehow? Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Not an answer, because I'm not sure what is going on in your code, but condition variables are not just signals, they should be used to signal a change in a shared condition.  See this example: http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/implementing-a-thread-safe-queue-using-condition-variables.html

Comment: In your code, the condition could be a busy flag, so stateMachine could have "busy = true; while (busy && ! rc) { rc = m_Condition.timed_wait(...); }"

Comment: @stefaanv Thanks for your suggestions. I read that article you posted and okay, maybe I am using the `timed_wait` not for usual intended purpose, but still it should do the deal. Actually the implementation they used there is quite the same as mine.
To your second comment: What should that busy flag do? I mean my problem is that my `timed_wait` only returns with a timeout and a return value of `false` after the first call. I can call `notify_all()` all I want .. doesn't change anything :/

Comment: actually, I don't see where it could fail in your code because notify_all can only be called when the mutex is locked which means that the other thread is in timed_wait, but still, it's not that difficult to include the busy flag and see (the doc's mention that you better pass the predicate when doing a relative timed_wait)

Comment: If however in your while(true) loop, you unlock the mutex, then the notify_all could be called before the thread is in timed_wait.

Comment: The mutex gets never unlocked in the while(true) loop (except at the time `timed_wait` is called ) so that can't be the problem. Again what could I try to see by adding a busy flag?

Comment: It might be better to post the minimal code that exposes the problem.  About the busy flag: it was just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, not the brightest hour for me I actually solved the problem. The above posted code is compiling and works as intended. The actual problem lied within the handling of Event or Timeout. Since the stuff that happened there is absolutely unrelated to the `timed_wait` I guess I don't need to explain it here. So this question can be closed.

**UPDATE:**

Of course the above code won't work since the lack of a dispatch method. Just for the sake of it I am gonna mention it here: For testing purposes I just create an Object of `myClass_A` in my main function, start the state machine and then call the `callbackEvent` from my main function. This actually works!

Comment: Well, the above posted code can't work as intended, because there is no dispatch and no callback, but your problem is solved, so that is the most important.

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not have to reset the condition variable, and yes it works multiple times.

I believe what you are seeing is a deadlock, rather than failure when waiting the second time on m_condition. When you call timed_wait() in stateMachine() your mutex will be unlocked, and it is re-locked when timed_wait() returns. I'm guessing that in the missing code which follows the wait you are calling callbackEvent(). That method attempts to lock the mutex, but it cannot because (a) it is already locked in the caller (stateMachine()) and (b) boost::mutex isn't re-entrant. You could try using e.g. recursive_mutex instead.

Comment: I thought so too, but the code ( which I omitted -> Timeout or Event ) is not very much. So if I play this through it would go like this:

1. `timed_wait` returns ( first time )
2.  "Event" Code is executed. 
3.  Next Command is dispatched
4.  `timed_wait` unlocks the mutex
5.  Callback can be executed 

Besides - I checked with the debugger - my code actually executes the `notify_all` multiple times